# Craters by screws where ceiling plaster has broken?

Tags: ceiling

I have some craters around screws in the ceiling. The screws themselves are not lose, so I am just wondering if filler will fix this issue. If I remove the flakes around the craters and add filler, specifically this one; https://www.screwfix.com/p/ronseal-big-hole-ready-mixed-wall-filler-grey-1-2ltr/95289

Will it do the trick?

Thank you very much!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the ceiling plaster like you say it is or is it drywall?  Please attach picture.

Comment: @PennyPincherWannaBeHandyMan sorry about that, added now. Not really sure which one of the two it is

Comment: @PennyPincherWannaBeHandyMan I believe it's drywall: going to pick this up as its cheap: https://www.screwfix.com/p/no-nonsense-interior-ready-mixed-filler-white-off-white-1kg/555gt

Comment: The real question is WHY is this happening?  If you don't resolve the root cause, it will happen again.

Comment: The color strikes me as odd. The link to "screwfix" leads me to believe you're in the UK, is that correct? Is that the normal color of drywall/plaster board over there? In the US, it's a very light grey. To my eye, that looks more like the color of MDF. Does it feel like paper, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re quite correct, a basic filler and sanded smooth once dry will work absolutely fine. There is no underline problem, the plaster has slightly different colours because it’s probably been skimmed at sometime.  This is a very common issue with a quick fix. Good luck!

Comment: Mostly agree (there might be an underlying issue with rafter/truss movement), but tighten the screws a tiny bit. FWIW, this is known over here as a 'nail pop' or a 'screw pop' if you wanted to spend some google time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @AloysiusDefenestrate found those in my searches, however it's not anything to do with the screws moving, and they are still in the same place and secure. Thanks all for the help :D